# How to dismiss alert dialog when javascript button is clicked in web-view in android

Tags: android

Below is the code what i tried so far:

```
TextView tv =findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_rect));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        WebView view =dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = view.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        view.loadUrl("https://www.journaldev.com");
        dialog.show();
    }
});
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

My requirement is load web-view in alert dialog and web-view has one java script button called "close" on click of close button inside web-view alert dialog should be dismissed.

How to achieve this in android?

Answer (score 0):

To bind a new interface between your JavaScript and Android code, call **addJavascriptInterface()**, passing it a class instance to bind to your JavaScript and an interface name that your JavaScript can call to access the class.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");


<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

[sample code is here](http://rapidprogrammer.com/android-how-to-call-native-java-methods-from-webview-javascript)